# Bootstrap 4 and column ordering

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded Bootstrap 4, set `$enable-flex true` and recompiled.

I have a question about Bootstrap 4 and flexbox.

If you reduce the size of Twitter homepage, you can see that "Who to follow" part is moving from right to the left side of the site (but main feed doesn't get effected by that), and this is the thing I want to do using Bootstrap 4 and flexbox. So, when I resize the window (for a hypothetical size like sm), `#right` will start after `#left`. `#middle` is the feed section.

How can I do it?

Here's my current setup.

```css
#left {
  background: yellow;
}
#middle {
  background: brown;
}
#right {
  background: #a8d6fe;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2" id="left">
      <div class="col-md-12">PROFILE</div>
      <div class="col-md-12" id="menu">MENU</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-7" id="middle">NEWS</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3" id="right">RIGHT PART</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try to change the `order` of `#middle` to `1` for the particular screen size ?

Comment: Can you give the link of the twitter page you're talking ?

Comment: @Yenne Info I'm talking about the newsfeed of Twitter, the page you see after you log in.

Comment: @DavidDomain yes, but it starts after the middle. I want it to behave like it belongs to #left.

Comment: Ok. I'm going away, I didn't have an account....

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a div with `col-` as a wrapper to order the flex items. Which makes sense, because only the flex items can be ordered. Not the flex container.

```css
@import url('https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

[class*="col-"] {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#left{
    background:yellow;
}

#middle {
    background:brown;
    order: 1;
}

#right {
    background:#a8d6fe;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2" id="left">
        <div class="col-md-12">PROFILE</div>
        <div class="col-md-12" id="menu">MENU</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-7" id="middle">NEWS</div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3" id="right">RIGHT PART</div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```